# Populate a field from a select option

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php/mysql simple app where at one point user can choose from a dropdown, a product. I have product in db and I want - when user select product1 from dropdown, the field called price to be filled up automatically with the value price from db.

```
choose product    |  price
```

Answer (score 2):

Database test

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `price` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_product` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `price`
--

INSERT INTO `price` (`id`, `id_product`, `price`) VALUES
(1, 1, 10.20),
(2, 2, 15.50);
```

Queries

```
public function getProductList() {
        $stmt=$this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM product');
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
    public function getProductPrice($product_id){
        $stmt=$this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM price WHERE id_product=?');
        $stmt->execute(array($product_id));
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $row['price'];
    }
```

Your demo file

```
<?php
    include_once('classes/DataLayer.class.php');
    $dl = new DataLayer();
    $product_list = $dl->getProductList();

?>


<html>

<head>
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getPrice(){
        $.get('script.php?product_id='+$('#product option:selected').val(), function(data){
            $(' #price ').val(data);
        })
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <select id="product" name="product" onchange="return getPrice()">
        <option value="">Select Product</option>
        <?php
            if(isset($product_list) && !empty($product_list)){
                foreach($product_list as $product){
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $product->id?>"><?php echo $product->productName?></option>
        <?php
                }
            }
        ?>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="price" id="price" >
</body>

</html>
```

Download demo files : [Downlaod](http://lescracks.com/php/download.php?f=test.rar)

Answer (score 1):

You have two solutions, but they both use javascript :

**Javascript without ajax :**

While retrieving the data, you create a javascript object which associate a product id with its price. Like this :

```
<script>
var products = {};

<?php while($row = ...) : ?>
    products[<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>] = <?php echo $row['product_price']; ?>;
<?php endwhile; ?>
</script>
```

When the user choose a product in the dropdown, you will use something like this (I'm using JQuery) :

```
$('#my_dropdown').change(function()
{
    val product_id = $(this).val();

    // access to the javascript object created while retrieving data
    val product_price = products[product_id].price;

    // set the price textbox
    $('#price').val(product_price + ' $');
});
```

**Javascript with ajax**

```
$('#my_dropdown').change(function()
{
    val product_id = $(this).val();

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'get_product_price.php?product_id=' + product_id,
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('#price').val(data + ' $');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please help other by providing some code. This make it clear what are you doing and what is wrong in it.

Without code, I can simply say:

You need data to be filled after user select product from dropdown. User will be doing it on his browser so you can't do anything there in PHP. You will need to send AJAX request on the server.

Learn a bit about AJAX and you can do it easily.

Comment: I will search about ajax...I don't have what code post it here because i have no ideea how to do it. I will try ajax and put some code here. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi again and thanks a lot for your help. I managed to this

test.php

```
<?php
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/admin/db/config.php';
    $time = time();
    $query="SELECT id,name FROM products WHERE active='1'";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $options=""; 
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $id_product=$row["id"];
        $name=$row["name"];
        $options=$options . "<option value=" ."'$id_product'" . ">" . $name . "</option>";
    }
?>
<html>
   <head>
       <title>Title</title>
   <script language="Javascript">
        function postRequest(strURL){
                 var xmlHttp;
                       if(window.XMLHttpRequest){ // For Mozilla, Safari, ...
                         var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                          }
                       else if(window.ActiveXObject){ // For Internet Explorer
                         var xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                          }
            xmlHttp.open('POST', strURL, true);
            xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
               if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
                   updatepage(xmlHttp.responseText);
                  }
            }
      xmlHttp.send(strURL);
       }

       function updatepage(str){
      document.getElementById('result').value = str;
       }

       function callValue(){
      var a = parseInt(document.form1.a.value);
      var url = "call.php?a=" + a + ";
      postRequest(url);
       }
   </script>
   </head>

   <body>
     <form name="form1">
       <input name="result" type="text" id="result">
    <table>
    <tr>
<?php
   echo "<td><SELECT NAME='a' id='a' onChange='callValue();'><option value='0'>Please select</option>$options</SELECT></td>";
?>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

call.php

```
<?php
$a=$_GET["a"];

require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/admin/db/config.php';
$time = time();

$query="SELECT id,price,note FROM produse WHERE id=$a";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $price=$row["price"];
}
   echo $price;
?>
```

In this example when i select a product from drop down i can display the price of the product in the input.

I want also to have another(s) inputs where to display others from products like notes...
Can someone help/point me?

Thanks a lot again